# How do I change my Steam username?

Tags: steam

My username on Steam is an old e-mail I no longer use.  Is there a way to change username?

Comment: My friend is stuck using an old `@hotmail.com` username a good several years since he's actually used that email account, I somewhat doubt you can.

Comment: The account name is still under your original email you registered with.  Fortunately you can change your actual "contact" email address.  I'm afraid we're stuck with these old email account names until they allow us to change it.

Comment: @NickT Same here.  Mine is an old Yahoo account.

Comment: My Steam username is an email address at a defunct ISP

Comment: Try to write to steam support, to see what you can do. Sometimes, some services allows this change, and they do it for you. I don't know if steam does it, but to try... you don't loose anyting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot change **login** name AFAIK, you can change only account **alias** for your friends (chat name and some games name). For alias change go to Steam->Settings->Friends.